# Can't directly output STL Vector's iterator values

Tags: c++, stl

I'm having a problem when trying to output STL iterator values in C++. The following code generates an error - no matter what template target I'm going to use:

```
template <typename T>
void outputVector(vector<T> &v)
{
    typename vector<T>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
```

The message is

> no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << iter.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = const Node*, _Container = std::vector >'

When replacing the for loop with

```
for(iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++)
{
    T t = *iter;
    cout << t << endl;
}
```

everything works just fine.

Do you have any problem what the problem might be? The used class "Node" overloads the "<<" operator by

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &o, Node &n)
{
o << "Hello World" << endl;
return o;
}
```

Comment: How do you overload the `<<` operator for that `Node` type?

Comment: Would you post some real code?

Comment: `no matter what template target I'm going to use` wrong

Comment: Try using the C++ Standard Library instead of the STL. You may find it more compatible with the usage of standard streams (the error text tells me that you're using `std::cout`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `operator<<` fails to take a reference to `const` for the second argument:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyType& obj);
```

This means the *temporary* `*iter` cannot bind to that argument.

---

Get into the habit of using `const` any place you don't need to modify an object:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyType const& obj);
```

Now, the reference argument can bind to the temporary. Huzzah!

---

<sup>This successful guess brought to you by the colour blue and the number 42.</sup>